# How do I rewrite shell execution shell into pipeline plugin

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an Jenkins job which execute by shell script. This script includes git pull, build project with makefile, and test runs.

Recently, We decide to use pipeline plugin to rewrite the script, so all these process will shows as pipeline output. So without checking log, and user can know the process of different steps.

The old shell code looks like

```
git checkout 
...
make build
...
test 
...
```

I currently did changes as

```
node{
    stage 'Checkout'
    sh '''
       git checkout
       ...
    '''

    stage 'Build'
    sh '''
       make build
       ...
    '''

    stage 'Test'
    sh '''
       test
       ...
    '''
}
```

It runs, but I feel so lame about my changes. Is there any better way to do this? Not just copy paste old code into some "node, stage, step" brackets, and use "sh ..." to run it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. The breaking down of your old job into separate stages Checkout/Build/Test seems to be the way to go with Jenkins 2 pipelines.

If you want to go further, here are a few tips you could look into :

#### Checkout

Pipelines are great, but they are even better when they can be versioned and reused. 
Instead of using a plain pipeline script inside the job description, you could choose to load a pipeline from a Git repository using "Pipeline script from SCM" option. You then have two options :

- Load the pipeline from your current working project, i.e. just put a `your-pipeline.groovy` alongside your code files and then just reference your Git project in the `Pipeline script from SCM` section of your job, and put `your-pipeline.groovy` in `Script Path` field.
- Load the pipeline from an external, pipeline-dedicated Git repository, and then load your Git project from this pipeline.

Both options allow pipelines to be edited as simple groovy files outside Jenkins, and more importantly it allows pipelines to be versioned.

However if you want to go further and need to reuse the same pipeline template for multiple projects (example : when working with lots of microservices), you can load another pipeline from any pipeline.
You could easily have a basic pipeline in your working project that does nothing but loading a more generic pipeline (common to many jobs).

#### Plugins

Sh is great because it allows you to do anything a shell provides, but you should consider the use of dedicated plugins to do specific things such as a checkout, a Maven build or a Junit test.

[Pipeline documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) is a great place to start when you're beggining with pipelines. From your example, you could go from :

```
node{
    stage 'Checkout'
    sh '''
       git checkout
       ...

    stage 'Build'
    sh '''
       make build
       ...

    stage 'Test'
    sh '''
       test
       ...
}
```

to :

```
node {
  stage 'Checkout'
  git url: 'https://your-git-repo.git'

  stage 'Build'
  sh '''
    make build

  stage 'Test'
  step([$class: 'ArtifactArchiver', artifacts: '**/target/*.jar', fingerprint: true])
  step([$class: 'JUnitResultArchiver', testResults: '**/target/surefire-reports/TEST-*.xml'])
}
```

Plugins, in addition to making the read a bit easier, allow you to use their advantages such as being able to mark a build as Unstable/Failed when your unit tests are failing.

Please check the [plugins compatibility](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/COMPATIBILITY.md) page for more information on which plugins can be used inside pipelines.

#### Nodes

Your `node {}` definition is sufficient but if you want to go further you can have a look at [running some of your code on slaves](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#using-slaves) or [running your stages in parallel](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md#creating-multiple-threads).

#### Sh

If you're runnig simple code in your sh, do not forget that you are now in a Groovy environment and that you can do lot of things with it (e.g. calculations) in Groovy instead of doing the work using shell script.

#### Pipeline syntax

For easier comprehension of what you can do with pipelines and what the syntax of your pipeline or a certain plugin should be, you could use `Pipeline Syntax` link available in the bottom section when editing a job. Both the snippet generator and the online documentation will help you for your first steps with pipelines !